# GMM regression and instruments count with xtabond2

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

I have to perform a difference GMM regression on my panel data. It's not important that it works, but if it does not I need robust motivation for why not.

My panel data is divided in two bigger groups, say A and B. Group A is the one I'm interested in, but I can also use group B in order to have more observations.
I'll report the analysis for group A here.

Group A has the following structure:
Time range: 2000 - 2017
Countries: 46
Total Observation: 855

I have run the following command:
xtabond2 y L(1/2).y L(1/5).x1 L(1/5).x2 x3 x4 x5 i.year x6 x7 , gmm(y, laglimits(3 17)) level(95) robust nolevel

See below for the output. My question is about the interpretation of the test results.

1. Number of instruments = 114, where does this number come from? I have counted 17-3 = 14 instruments using gmm(y, laglimits(3 17)).
2. My interpretation of the Sargan and Hansen test to be so extremely different is that I have too many instruments. Is this correct? What would be a correct amount of instruments for this panel data frame?
3. Following my guess in "Second" I have collapsed the instruments, with the result of not having enough of them for all the independent variables. Reducing the variables (using only L(1/2).y L(1/5).x1 L(1/5).x2 x3 x4 x5), I get Sargan and Hansen test both 0. I interpret this result as not enough instruments for the GMM to work (see also that the confidence intervals are huge!). Is this correct?

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Best,
Al

Results without collapse:

```
    Warning: Number of instruments may be large relative to number of observations.
    Warning: Two-step estimated covariance matrix of moments is singular.
    Using a generalized inverse to calculate robust weighting matrix for Hansen test.
    Difference-in-Sargan/Hansen statistics may be negative.
    
    Dynamic panel-data estimation, one-step difference GMM
    
        

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Group variable: rec_num Number of obs = 421
    Time variable : year Number of groups = 38
    Number of instruments = 114 Obs per group: min = 1
    Wald chi2(0) = . avg = 11.08
    Prob > chi2 = . max = 12
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Robust
    y | Coef. Std. Err. z P>|z| [95% Conf. Interval]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    y |
    L1. | 1.036468 .1018369 10.18 0.000 .8368714 1.236065
    L2. | -.0963504 .0962006 -1.00 0.317 -.2849002 .0921994
    |
    x1 |
    L1. | .089542 .0441289 2.03 0.042 .003051 .176033
    L2. | .0393409 .0382197 1.03 0.303 -.0355683 .1142501
    L3. | .0478129 .0426604 1.12 0.262 -.0358 .1314258
    L4. | .0198056 .039333 0.50 0.615 -.0572856 .0968968
    L5. | .0234038 .0162282 1.44 0.149 -.0084029 .0552104
    |
    x2 |
    L1. | .2041297 .4241463 0.48 0.630 -.6271818 1.035441
    L2. | -1.406561 .9287444 -1.51 0.130 -3.226867 .4137444
    L3. | 1.443707 1.04289 1.38 0.166 -.6003206 3.487735
    L4. | -.8051038 1.117525 -0.72 0.471 -2.995412 1.385205
    L5. | .1804152 .6355273 0.28 0.777 -1.065195 1.426026
    |
    x3 | -.0055827 .0121747 -0.46 0.647 -.0294446 .0182793
    x4 | -.8350265 .5592689 -1.49 0.135 -1.931173 .2611204
    x5 | -.0019361 .0019381 -1.00 0.318 -.0057347 .0018624
    |
    year |
    2005 | .2457214 .9466613 0.26 0.795 -1.609701 2.101143
    2006 | .1571051 .7962133 0.20 0.844 -1.403444 1.717655
    2007 | .2607094 .7426875 0.35 0.726 -1.194931 1.71635
    2008 | .0978737 .6215058 0.16 0.875 -1.120255 1.316003
    2009 | .0229705 .5160136 0.04 0.964 -.9883975 1.034338
    2010 | -.0131881 .4455538 -0.03 0.976 -.8864576 .8600813
    2011 | -.0884742 .3828411 -0.23 0.817 -.838829 .6618805
    2012 | -.1563695 .3273156 -0.48 0.633 -.7978962 .4851573
    2013 | -.1322291 .2503104 -0.53 0.597 -.6228286 .3583703
    2014 | -.0865552 .1865422 -0.46 0.643 -.4521712 .2790608
    2015 | -.0423805 .1207112 -0.35 0.726 -.2789701 .1942091
    2016 | -.019548 .0672854 -0.29 0.771 -.151425 .1123291
    |
    x6 | -544.3496 737.4712 -0.74 0.460 -1989.767 901.0674
    x7 | 543.7989 737.9421 0.74 0.461 -902.541 1990.139
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Instruments for first differences equation
    GMM-type (missing=0, separate instruments for each period unless collapsed)
    L(3/17).hiv_inf
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Arellano-Bond test for AR(1) in first differences: z = -1.49 Pr > z = 0.137
    Arellano-Bond test for AR(2) in first differences: z = 1.34 Pr > z = 0.180
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sargan test of overid. restrictions: chi2(85) = 142.00 Prob > chi2 = 0.000
    (Not robust, but not weakened by many instruments.)
    Hansen test of overid. restrictions: chi2(85) = 7.86 Prob > chi2 = 1.000
    (Robust, but weakened by many instruments.)
```

Result with collapse:

```
Dynamic panel-data estimation, one-step difference GMM
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group variable: rec_num Number of obs = 422
Time variable : year Number of groups = 38
Number of instruments = 15 Obs per group: min = 1
Wald chi2(0) = . avg = 11.11
Prob > chi2 = . max = 12
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Robust
y | Coef. Std. Err. z P>|z| [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
y |
L1. | -1.547281 17.0422 -0.09 0.928 -34.94939 31.85483
L2. | 1.268705 14.11864 0.09 0.928 -26.40332 28.94073
|
x1 |
L1. | .5364254 5.925459 0.09 0.928 -11.07726 12.15011
L2. | 1.118569 8.584004 0.13 0.896 -15.70577 17.94291
L3. | -.9398232 12.59783 -0.07 0.941 -25.63112 23.75147
L4. | 1.369626 8.409769 0.16 0.871 -15.11322 17.85247
L5. | -.3716305 2.506262 -0.15 0.882 -5.283814 4.540553
|
x2 |
L1. | 13.32372 169.2516 0.08 0.937 -318.4034 345.0508
L2. | -1.634898 59.74055 -0.03 0.978 -118.7242 115.4544
L3. | -20.85329 226.6722 -0.09 0.927 -465.1226 423.416
L4. | 22.77116 243.3968 0.09 0.925 -454.2778 499.8201
L5. | -7.901386 52.83028 -0.15 0.881 -111.4468 95.64406
|
x3 | .2881728 3.929217 0.07 0.942 -7.412952 7.989297
x4 | -13.31332 99.59179 -0.13 0.894 -208.5096 181.883
x5 | .0391301 .1761786 0.22 0.824 -.3061737 .3844339
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instruments for first differences equation
GMM-type (missing=0, separate instruments for each period unless collapsed)
L(3/17).hiv_inf collapsed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arellano-Bond test for AR(1) in first differences: z = 0.11 Pr > z = 0.910
Arellano-Bond test for AR(2) in first differences: z = 0.13 Pr > z = 0.899
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sargan test of overid. restrictions: chi2(0) = 0.00 Prob > chi2 = .
(Not robust, but not weakened by many instruments.)
Hansen test of overid. restrictions: chi2(0) = 0.00 Prob > chi2 = .
(Robust, but weakened by many instruments.)
```